# eclipse not detecting change in json file

Tags: java, jquery, json, eclipse, servlets

Hey i am trying to create a program in which a json file is written upon a request to servlet 
and the json file is read using jquery script in jsp.So far successful .But the problem now i am facing is that first time it works fine then the second time onwards when when servlet is requested again the content of the file is overwritten as desired.But change is seen both in Hard disk i mean filesystem and project explorer in eclipse but upon reloading page and using firebug when i see the returned json file  it contains previous data after doing this two or three times the new result appears has anyone experienced it ?????
s therey any bypassing ways

Comment: please anybody respond

Comment: Clear your browser's cache and try again. And chill out please :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your ajax request is being cached...

You could try adding the current date time to a variable at the end of the URL you are requesting. Its a workaround to force a fresh load of the resource:

```
"http://localhost/service/user/?"+new Date().getTime()
```

Comment: Yeah I Did that So that each request looks like new one did no-caching with meta tags and response object but nothing worked the problem is that when i write into file only when i double click and open it only the change is reflected else when read is performed old data is display if i double click and open it before read it detects the new data that whats bugs me